# MoveGroupSequence PILZ plan only multiple unrelated trajectories

Tags: ros, python, moveit, ros-melodic, motionplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I plan ONLY multiple linear trajectories that are independent of each other?

For my use case, I want to plan several trajectories starting from different states and they are unrelated of each other.
I am using the SimpleActionClient `actionlib.SimpleActionClient("/sequence_move_group", moveit_msgs.msg.MoveGroupSequenceAction)`. When planning the first trajectory, the result is okay, however when I send the second trajectory to be planned I get the following error:

> [ERROR] [1623032769.603690338]: > Planning pipeline threw an exception (error code: -17): Only the first request is allowed to have a start state, but the requests for group: "b_bot" violate the rule

As I understand, the "SequenceManager" seems to interpret the second trajectory as part of the first and then it complains that `only the first request is allowed to have a start state`. However, how do I tell the "SequenceManager" that the two trajectories are not part of the same sequence and that just treat the second request as a **new** request?

If I use the SimpleActionClient with the `planning_options.plan_only = False`, the first trajectory is planned and executed correctly, then the second trajectory is planned and executed correctly. However if the request is `planning_options.plan_only = True` the I get the above mentioned error. I do not want to plan1->execute1->plan2->execute2, I want to plan1->plan2->execute1->execute2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379703/movegroupsequence-pilz-plan-only-multiple-unrelated-trajectories/) by [cambel07](https://answers.ros.org/users/50158/cambel07/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2021-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cambel07](https://answers.ros.org/users/50158/cambel07/) on 2021-06-07**:
My bad, for both trajectories I was using the move_group to construct the `MotionSequenceRequest`. However, for the first trajectory I use the default value of `start_state` so it worked fine, but for the second trajectory I was setting a desired `start_state` which was being included in each point of the trajectory. Thus, the planner was complaining about that.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-06-07**:
Could you post your comment as an answer (ideally with some example code) and accept it, so the question is out of the Unanswered queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For both trajectories I was using the move_group to construct the MotionSequenceRequest. However, for the first trajectory I use the default value of start_state so it worked fine, but for the second trajectory I was setting a desired start_state which was being included in each point of the trajectory. Thus, the planner was complaining about that.

Before:

```
    msi = moveit_msgs.msg.MotionSequenceItem()
    msi.req = group.construct_motion_plan_request()
    msi.blend_radius = 0.0
    motion_plan_requests.append(msi)

    msi.req.start_state = start_state

    for wp in waypoints:
        group.set_pose_target(wp)
        msi = moveit_msgs.msg.MotionSequenceItem()
        msi.req = group.construct_motion_plan_request()
        msi.blend_radius = blend_radius
        motion_plan_requests.append(msi)
```

After:

```
    msi  = moveit_msgs.msg.MotionSequenceItem()
    msi.req = group.construct_motion_plan_request()
    msi.blend_radius = 0.0
    motion_plan_requests.append(msi)

    msi.req.start_state = start_state

    for wp in waypoints:
        group.set_pose_target(wp)
        msi = moveit_msgs.msg.MotionSequenceItem()
        msi.req = group.construct_motion_plan_request()
        msi.req.start_state = moveit_msgs.msg.RobotState() # Here, resetting the start_state for each point
        msi.blend_radius = blend_radius
        motion_plan_requests.append(msi)
```

---

Originally posted by [cambel07](https://answers.ros.org/users/50158/cambel07/) with karma: 92 on 2021-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1